# FTP upload over browser

Tags: php

I wanted to know, if we can create a web based application like filezilla. if yes, any information would be helpful for me. I tried searching Google, but couldn't get proper info. All I'm getting is the sites which provide this service e.g http://www.txftp.com/
Not how to go about creating such a website.

Answer (score 1):

When you create web based application, this becomes http protocol, what you actually end up doing is upload and download of files over the http protocols. building the similar look and feel like Filezilla is quite easy, but achieving same performance and guarantee will be difficult.

One way to achieve this can be by writing java applets. You can use any ready made java ftp libraries to code this applet. http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html.
You may have to create a policy and sign the applet so that user allows your applet to open a ftp socket connection from the applet.

In case if you are ok with HTML5, you can explore into WebSockets for the solution.
http://mustafaakin.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/introducing-websocket-file-transfer/

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of FTP tutorials online, first look into the [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php) that starts it all:

```
<?php

$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

?>
```

Comment: The user nterface will require you using the FTP Functions and designing with HTML/CSS/Javscript http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php